# Using vaiables in test definition for rspec

Tags: rspec

I'm not sure how to make variables defined in the before block be available in the test description. Here is what I mean.

```
context "name" do
  before do
    @min_size = 1
    @max_size = 255
  end
  context "is valid when it" do
    it "has #{@min_size} character" do
      expect(create(:person, name: Faker::Lorem.characters(@min_size))).to be_valid
    end
    it "has #{@max_size} characters" do
      expect(create(:person, name: Faker::Lorem.characters(@max_size))).to be_valid
    end
    it "has between #{@min_size} and #{@max_size} characters" do
      expect(create(:person, name: Faker::Lorem.characters((@min_size + @max_size)/2))).to be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

The 3 tests pass, but this is how the output prints. Notice the missing min and max values.

```
name
  is valid when it
    has  character
    has  characters
    has between  and  characters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
context "name" do
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 255

  before do
    @min_size = min_size
    @max_size = max_size
  end

  context "is valid when it" do
    it "has #{min_size} character" do
    ...
```

Pay attention to omitting '@' sign in `it`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's more or less confusing than the first answer, but given the benefits of staying away from use of instance variables in RSpec tests (i.e. because they evaluate to `nil` if undefined), you could use `let` instead of `before` which allows you to use the same variable throughout your example.

```
context "name" do
  min_size = 1
  max_size = 255

  let(:min_size) {min_size}
  let(:max_size) {max_size}

  context "is valid when it" do
    it "has #{min_size} character" do
    ...
```

Comment: Works well too, but have a question. When defined within the 'context' which has multiple tests, are the variables defined with @ or let operate within the scope of the context or can they be accessed outside of it as well? Just trying to understand.

Comment: The variables are accessible within the blocks defined within the context and it's descendants, but not elsewhere.